# .httaccess redirect from old domain to new domain into a directory

Tags: .htaccess

i have to domains which DNS shows on the same server. Now I would like to make a htaccess-redirect from one Domain (old domain) to a directory on the new domain

exampl:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.ch$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.ch$
 RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.ch/de/besuchen/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I put these file on the root of the newdomain.ch but if I open olddomain.ch it only shows me the homepage and not the side /de/besuchen

thanks for help.

Comment: _" which DNS shows on the same server"_ - that does not necessarily mean that they both get routed into the same directory. _"it only shows me the homepage"_ - the old, or the new one?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Usage: These rules will redirect all traffic from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`.